# Disable multiple plugin updates in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I use the below code in my `wp-config` to disable multiple plugins?

For example, this code will stop plugin.php from updating but how can I disable multiple in an `array` so that plugin.php, plugin1.php and plugin2.php are also disabled.

```
/* Function which remove Plugin Update Notices */
function disable_plugin_updates( $value ) {
   unset( $value->response['plugin/plugin.php'] );
   return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'disable_plugin_updates' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Function which remove Plugin Update Notices */
function disable_plugin_updates( $values ) {

   foreach($values as $value) {
       unset( $value->response['plugin/plugin.php'] );
   }
   return;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'disable_plugin_updates' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is giving me warning, it should be like this.

```
/** Disable update check **/        
function disable_plugin_updates( $value ) {
      if ( isset($value) && is_object($value) ) {
        if ( isset( $value->response['plugin/plugin.php'] ) ) {
          unset( $value->response['plugin/plugin.php'] );
        }
      }
      return $value;
    }
    add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'disable_plugin_updates' );
```